# Point a partical on a sphere geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Below is my snippet, For now i want to position a single particle on the sphere. How can i combine partical and sphere geometries together ? Once this is achieved i want to render particles on top of the sphere dynamically

```
      init();
      animate();

      function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
        camera.position.z = 500;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader.load( '<%= image_path('earthmap1k.jpg') %>', function ( texture ) {
          geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20 );
          material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5, wireframe: true } );
          mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
          scene.add( mesh );
        } );

  function addPartical() {
    var distance = 200;
    ggeometry  = new THREE.Geometry();
    vertex     = new THREE.Vector3();
    theta      = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360);
    phi        = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360);

    vertex.x = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
    vertex.y = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
    vertex.z = distance * Math.cos(theta);

    ggeometry.vertices.push(vertex);

    particles = new THREE.Points(ggeometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
    particles.boundingSphere = 50;
    scene.add(particles);
  };

      }



      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        addParticle();
        render();
      }

      function render() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
```

Comment: You are just drawing a sphere here. Where is the code for the particles?

Comment: @gaitat I edited my answer to add particles. But in this case, as these are two different geometries, world map and particles are not tied to each other. I want to map a particle onto the sphere ..such that even though the sphere rotates, particle sticks to it

Comment: You are drawing particles on a sphere of radius equal to your `distance` variable. You are also drawing a sphere of the same radius. So your particles should fall on the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat the two objects as one use a `THREE.Object3D()` and manipulate that.

Comment: I actually solved the problem using `new THREE.Group();` ... adding `sphere geometry` and `particles`to group instead of scene ..but ill see what `Object3D` can be used in this case